# Binding custom RequestHeader and RequestBody in Spring Controller

Tags: hibernate, rest, api, spring-boot

Is it possible to use @RepositoryRestController to benefit from binding, auto-validating and persisting Header data, while also managing binary data in the @RequestBody ?

Consider the following call to an API, uploading a document:

```
curl -X POST /document \
--header "Custom-Header: {\"dimensions\": \"200x300\" }" \
--header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
--data-binary @file.pdf
```

With Metadata.class and a silly example validator:

```
public class Metadata {
    @Size(max = 20)
    String dimensions;

    // Some other code
}
```

How would the Controller get the best of all worlds?  This (and a number of alternatives) don't seem to do the job:

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class MetadataController {

    @PostMapping("/document")
    public @ResponseBody Metadata uploadDocument(@RequestHeader("Custom-Header") String dimensions,
                                                 @Valid Metadata metadata) {

        // do something with the @RequestBody
    }
```

I should mention that the **dimensions** value and the validator are arbitrary; suffice to say that in this scenario the metadata is only relevant to the file within the current domain, and so shouldn't be embedded within the file itself.

It would also be good to provide custom error handling with such a setup, which also appear to be complicated in such a scenario.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Can I bind (and validate) Header data to a model, while also using the Body of a request?

Comment: FWIW, I ended up just managing this manually, without binding the request to the model.  Never found out if it was possible..